# Error when downloading the file C#

Tags: c#, system.net, system.net.webexception

My code:

```
string dir = "/Users/valeria/Desktop/screening/"+cell;
string remoteUri ="http://www.broadinstitute.org%2Fcmap%2FviewScan.jsp%3Ftype%3DCEL%26scan%3D"+p;
            string pFileName = dir + "/p";

            using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
            {
                myWebClient.DownloadFile(remoteUri, pFileName);

            }
```

My program creates a file `pFileName`, but doesn't download anything because I get the following exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: Could not find a part of
>   the path
>   "/Users/valeria/Projects/screening/screening/bin/Debug/http:/www.broadinstitute.org/cmap/viewScan.jsp?type=CEL&scan=EC2003090503AA".
>   ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path
>   "/Users/valeria/Projects/screening/screening/bin/Debug/http:/www.broadinstitute.org/cmap/viewScan.jsp?type=CEL&scan=EC2003090503AA"

What's wrong?

Comment: You might want to look at the value of your variable 'cell'.

Comment: @AdrianWragg everything is OK with it. The program creates the file. Cell is just a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The escaped URI certainly isn't helping. URL-encoding is generally only used when the item you are encoding is being appended to a URL; encoding the URL itself is unnecessary and can lead to other problems.

I would strongly suggest changing

```
  string remoteUri="http://www.broadinstitute.org%2Fcmap%2FviewScan.jsp%3Ftype%3DCEL%26scan%3D"+p;
```

to

```
  string remoteUri ="http://www.broadinstitute.org/cmap/viewScan.jsp?type=CEL&scan="+p;
```

and re-trying.

Comment: @FabianBigler - I read straight past it the first time, don't worry - then, I tried actually running it in a console app!

Comment: @AdrianWragg fair enough. I thought it had to do with the filename, because the error indicated that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The variable cell is - as pointed out by Adrian Wragg - wrong.

Your error already indicates your problem (the bold part is what's in your cell-variable)
"/Users/valeria/Projects/screening/screening/**bin/Debug/http:/www.broadinstitute.org/cmap/viewScan.jsp?type=CEL&scan=EC2003090503AA**"

So make sure you provide a valid path.

If you don't believe me, you can check your filepath like this:

```
If (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(dir))
{
Stop; //<== if it hits here, we are right. ;-)
}
```

Comment: when I don't use dir and jus write 
myWebClient.DownloadFile(remoteUri, "file.txt");
I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

1: You are using encoded Uri, so you have to decode your Uri using System.Web.HttpUtility:

```
string decodedUri = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(remoteUri);
```

Then, you will get proper Uri:

> http://www.broadinstitute.org/cmap/viewScan.jsp?type=CEL&scan=EC2003090503AA

Which you should pass to `myWebClient`:

```
myWebClient.DownloadFile(decodedUri, pFileName);
```

2: Your `cell` variable points to url, so you have to fix it. You can assign it as `string.Empty` or remove it temporary to see if that solution works.